# Forcing sql_mode to "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" still got warning Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, pymysql

I'm using `Django 2.1.3` ,`pymysql 0.9.2`, `mysql 5.7`, `python3.5`

`sql_mode in mysql:`

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

`db setting in django:`

```py
DATABASES = {

  'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4'
         },
}
```

And I always get warning like this:

```py
/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (3135, "'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.")
  result = self._query(query)

/venv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (3090, "Changing sql mode 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' is deprecated. It will be removed in a future release.")
  result = self._query(query)
```

Why I got the warning like above?

Any commentary is very welcome. great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4'
         },
}
```

You can also see [warnings — Warning control](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#module-warnings).